# needing custom DataGridviewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need a simple custom DataGridviewCell to ... I can t explain exactly what i want

Suppose there is a cell containing a string ! I want to change(custom format) this string before shown! 
and if cell changed, save in previous format in underlying db;

Something like "Man in the middle" in network Hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to Specify a StringFormat. 
You can use `dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "your format";`
You can use `FormattedValue` to work with the displayed value and `Value` to work with the real value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the event DataBindingComplete and from there apply you custom format to whatever column you want